# Error in the api microsoft azure translator

Tags: azure

Error in the api microsoft azure translator when using directly from the page gives me this error and followed the steps to follow directly from the page and still not able to do it

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Bearer eyj0....
```

remove the "" and the +